# How to avoid useless mapStateToProps()?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

Assume a React + Redux application with a page that contains [**~100** MUI checkboxes](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox).

All of these are controlled using Redux state, like so:

```
let CheckboxComponent = React.createClass({

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.activeList !== this.props.activeList;
  }

  render() {

    let isChecked = this.props.activeList.indexOf(this.props.myId) >= 0;

    return <Checkbox
      checked={isChecked}
    />;
  }

});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    activeList: state.form.myForm.values.activeList;
  };
}

CheckboxComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(CheckboxComponent);
```

Now, let's say that I also have a controlled `<input>` on the same page, using the same Redux store. Each keypress in the input will cause a Redux state change. So, while typing this will cause many changes, **but not for `activeList`**.

My concern is that - if I'm not wrong - `mapStateToProps` and in consequence `shouldComponentUpdate` of each `<CheckboxComponent>` gets called on each keystroke - **that's a few hundred useless function calls**.

Fortunately, `shouldComponentUpdate` will avoid a useless re-render, but in practice my `shouldComponentUpdate` is more complex and thus slightly expensive (even if less expensive than a re-render).

All that could be solved if `mapStateToProps()` would not be called for Redux state changes that *don't* involve `activeList`.

Is such an optimization possible in some way?

Comment: did you try using onblur event against onchange?

Comment: The input field is just an example to make the problem clear. The page contains a multitude of different input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different answers to this question.

First: no, you can't avoid `mapState` calls for connected components that "aren't affected".  By definition, Redux only has a single event emitter, and does not track what parts of the state *might* have changed during a dispatch.  It's up to each individual subscriber to check the new state and see if there's a relevant change.

Second: yes, dispatching a separate action for every individual keystroke isn't particularly efficient.  I've handled that in my own app by writing a higher-order component that uses its state to buffer changes for faster re-rendering of inputs, while debouncing action dispatching.  I have [that component available in a gist](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/554cab15d83fd994dfab) - made a couple updates since then, but that's the general idea.  You may also want to look at libraries such as [React-Reformed](https://github.com/davezuko/react-reformed), [React-Form](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-form), or [React-Redux-Form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form), which provide some similar pieces that probably have had more work put into them then my bit of code.

Third: it looks like you're passing around an array of "active" items to each individual checkbox component, and comparing indices inside that component.  That's not a very performant pattern.  A better approach would probably be for the parent component to have a list of IDs, pass an ID to each connected child, and have each child look up its own data by ID in its `mapState`.  See these slides on [High-Performance Redux](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/) for more information.  I also have other info on [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) as part of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).